# setting TabItem.Content with viewmodel is not showing view from data template

Tags: c#, wpf

In code I have a datatemplate in a resource dictionary

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ContainerViewModel}"  x:Key="ContainerTemplate">
    <my:ContainerView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

This resource dictionary is added in app.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/DataTemplates.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

In the code I am trying to set a tab item with view model

```
var vm = new ContainerViewModel();
tabItem.Content = vm;
```

the tabitem just shows the viewmodel name. It is not looking up the data template an showing the view. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `tabItem.Content = vm` here you trying to add C# class as content of TabItem, so it'll fire `vm.ToString()` and will show just name of ViewModel. You should set View as Content

Comment: Remove x:Key="ContainerTemplate"

Comment: That sorted it Babbillumpa

Comment: @Jimmy Great for that.